# How to prevent browser (IE..) to block popup for posting on facebook friend timeline?

Tags: javascript, facebook, callback, popup

I've a question about the popup post of my application.
Basically the application create an image.
There is a button, once it's clicked an ajax call is done, with ImageMagick it is created the image, then the code returns to javascript that calls *postImage()* function, that opens the popup for posting to a friend profile the image.

Is there a way to prevent this popup to be blocked?
Which approach / solution should I take?

```
    function postImage(sIdFriend, sIdPostcard, sPathPostcard){
        var hFacebookData = {
            method: 'feed',
            to: sIdFriend,
            display : 'popup',
            link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP/',
            picture: 'https://fb.thesecretpages.nl/MY_APP/image.png',
            name: 'MY_APP_NAME',
            caption: 'MY_APP_CAPTION',
            description: 'MY_APP_DESCRIPTION'
        };

        function callback(response) {
            window.parent.location.href = "https://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP/?st=4";
        }


        FB.ui(hFacebookData, callback);
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, the only way is really to call immediately the popup and after that make the ajax call, so while the user deal with the popup and posting it is redirected to the timeline of the friend, the ajax operation goes on and is executed.

the ajax call provoke the blocking of popup.

i read about it on stackoverflow for login popup, it's the same for posting popup too.